# How to detect patterns in a data set of given IP addresses using a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, pattern-recognition

How to detect patterns in a data set of given IP addresses using a neural network?

The data set is actually a list of all the vulnerable devices on a network. I want to use a neural network that detctes any patters in the occurrences of these vulnerabilities with reference to their IPs and ports.

Comment: is your dataset purely (ip, vulenerable) pairs or is there more, like a temporal aspect, etc

Comment: @mshlis the data set is purely (ip, vulnerable) pairs.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to detect *ranges* of IP addresses that are vulnerable/dangerous/etc, right? Such ranges are essentially numeric intervals, and so my suggestion is to look at [decision tree learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning) instead of neural networks, because you are essentially doing a classification task where you want to test both categorical data and splits over numerical attributes.

The result will be a tree-like function (nested conditionals) of the form

```
IF ...> address > ... 
   THEN [vulnerable]
   ELSE IF port=... 
              THEN [not vulnerable]
              ELSE [vulnerable]
```

where a huge benefit is that it is also more human-readable than a neural net.

The most prominent algorithms for decision trees are [ID 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm) and its successor [C4.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm).

Comment: I have the data sets of couputers that is purely of the type (ip, vulnerability). I know which devices are vulnerable. I just want to detect a pattern to the occurrence of these vulnerable computers.

Comment: Could you please state more specifically what you mean by a "pattern"? What would be the desired outcome of the learning process? Could you perhaps give a small example?

Comment: After the learning process, I want it to give a general rule as to where in an network do the vulnerabilities occur with reference to thier IPs.

Comment: So the goal is to learn a mapping {IP addresses} -> {vulnerabilities}. Learning always involves some form of generalization or abstraction. In which direction should this happen? Is it "since addresses A,B,C have vulnerability X, neighbouring address D likely also has X" or the other way round, i.e. "addresses that have vulnerabilities X and Y often also have Z"?

Comment: the first type i.e. Is it "since addresses A,B,C have vulnerability X, neighbouring address D likely also has X.

Comment: Then the next question is what kind of structure you are able to exploit. In order for learning to happen, there has to be some way to _generalize_, meaning we have to be able to say that address D is in some sense similar/related/close to A,B,C. If all we have is the addresses themselves, all I can think of is treating them as numbers and assuming numbers close to each other are in a way "similar". This makes sense to a certain degree, namely when a group of addresses with the same prefix belong to the same subnet, and this is why I suggest attempting to learn address _ranges_ (=intervals).

Comment: That is exactly what I had in mind.